# GCM message sent from one IP but not from another

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When I send a `GCM` push notification to an Android device from my own computer, the message is successfully delivered. But when I use the same program via my colleague's workstation, it is not.

I remember there was this step in which we had to register an `IP` before Google allows us to send push messages via that `IP`, but I just cannot remember what that process was called.

Comment: I think you added server restriction during generation of server key at google console. update  that from google console

Comment: @USKMobility I did not create the server key. Should I contact the company who has developed the app to add the new station `IP`?

Comment: Yes, you should ask query, if they put any restriction related to IP or domain ,update them as required (with new one)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just adding to USKMobility's answer so you have an idea what it looks like. Whitelisting an IP is found in the Server API Key section under *"Accept requests from these server IP addresses"*.